# Error: repository checked out but no solution found - when cloning Github repo using Visual Studio 2019 for Mac

Tags: github, visual-studio-2019, git-clone

Using Visual Studio for Mac (vs 8.10.14) I am trying to clone an existing Github repository.
In Visual Studio I navigate to ***Version Control/Clone Repository***... I fill out the https path (copied from my Github repo) and hit the **Clone** button. Prompted for Username I enter my Github username and for password I use my freshly generated PAT (Personal Access Token) with credentials for "repo"=*Full control of private repositories*.
Then the clone process starts but immediately stops with error message: "**Repository checked out but no solution found**". After selecting the only option "**OK**", the process stops fully without cloning a single line of code.

Has anyone found a solution already?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, were you able to solve it?